# Recursion-like sequences which are hard to relate recursively

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations

Consider the sequence
\begin{align*}
   a_1&=1\\
   a_2&=2+\sqrt1\\
   a_3&=3+\sqrt{2+\sqrt1}\\
   &\kern5.5pt\vdots\\
   a_n&=n+\sqrt{n-1+\sqrt{\cdots+\sqrt{1}}}.
\end{align*}
Something like this is easy to work with inductively, since we can simply relate $a_n = n+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$, and prove things that way. But now consider something which instead unfolds "on the inside", such as
\begin{align*}
   b_1&=1\\
   b_2&=1+\sqrt2\\
   b_3&=1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\\
   &\kern5.5pt\vdots\\
   b_n&=1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\cdots+\sqrt{n}}},
\end{align*}
where it is not easy to relate $b_n$ to $b_{n-1}$. How does one work with such sequences, where we are typically interested in the same sorts of questions? Or another example, consider the sequence
\begin{align*}
   c_1&=1\\
   c_2&=1(1+2)\\
   c_3&=1(1+2(1+3))\\
   c_4&=1(1+2(1+3(1+4)))\\
   &\kern5.5pt\vdots\\
   c_n&=1(1+2(1+3(1+\cdots+(n-1)(1+n)\cdots))).
\end{align*}
Is it possible to prove inductively that $c_n = 1!+2!+\cdots+n!$, even though there is no obvious way to relate $c_n$ to $c_{n-1}$?

Comment: you still relate $c_n$ to $c_{n-1}$ or $b_n$ to $b_{n-1}$ in some way, or express sequence directly like $f(n) = n + 1$ forall $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ in the end you need to write down some rule explicitly only after that you will be able to work and prove properties about the sequence, and yes you will be able to prove that $c_n = n!$

Comment: You will be very interesed in a document by Dixon Jones [arXiv:1707.06139](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06139) "A chronology of continued square roots and other continued compositions, through the year 2016" or the Wikipedia article [Nested radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical) just for square roots.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer lies in looking at multivariable functions. Let's take your second example.
Define the function $$g(n,x)=\begin{cases}g(n-1,(n-1)(1+x))& \text{if } n > 1 \\x& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ where $n\in\mathbb{N},x\in\mathbb{R}$.

It's easy to verify that $c_n=g(n,n)$.

Next, you can show that $g$ is an affine function in the second argument via induction. The base case is trivial since $g(1,x)=x$.

Now suppose $g(n,\cdot)$ is affine, meaning $$\exists k_n\in\mathbb{R}:\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}:g(n,x)-g(n,y)=k_n(x-y)$$
Then for arbitrary $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
$$g(n+1,x)-g(n+1,y)=g(n,n(1+x))-g(n,n(1+y))=k_nn(1+x-(1+y))=k_nn(x-y)$$ where we used the induction hypothesis in the 3rd equality. So our $k_{n+1}=k_nn$ which concludes the proof.

Since $g(n,\cdot)$ is affine, we would like to know the additive constant, so let's plug in $0$ and we get $g(n,0)=g(n-1,n-1)=c_{n-1}$. So we get the simple recursion $$c_{n+1}=g(n+1,n+1)=k_{n+1}(n+1)+c_n$$

And with the recursion $k_{n+1}=k_nn$ that we got before, we can easily solve for $c_n$ now.

Now, I unfortunately don't have a canonical answer. For example, I don't know how to use this approach for your first example. However, I have often found that going "2D" and trying to find simple recursions there, was the way to go.

(EDIT: After playing around a bit, using this approach for $b_n$, I haven't gotten a closed-form or a limit, however, it is easy to show that the sequence is increasing and bounded from above and therefore convergent and that the forwards difference goes to $0$. 2 things that I honestly wouldn't have seen at first glance.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add $x$.

Let

$$\begin{align*}
   c_1'&=1x\\
   c_2'&=1(1+2x)\\
   c_3'&=1(1+2(1+3x))\\
   c_4'&=1(1+2(1+3(1+4x)))\\
   &\kern5.5pt\vdots\\
   c_n'&=1(1+2(1+3(1+\cdots+(n-1)(1+nx)\cdots))).
\end{align*}$$

So we know that $c_n'$ is $c_{n-1}'$ put $x$ as $(1+nx)$. Let $c_n'=A_n+B_nx$. So we have $A_n=A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}$ and $B_{n}=nB_{n-1}$. So you may need the recurrance relation like this.

To prove $c_n' = 1!+2!+\cdots+n!$ recursively, we can use induction to prove $A_{n}=1!+2!+\cdots+(n-1)!$ and $B_n=n!$. If this holds for $n-1$, we have $A_n=A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}=(1!+2!+\cdots+(n-2)!)+(n-1)!=1!+2!+\cdots+(n-1)!$, $B_n=nB_{n-1}=n\times (n-1)!=n!$. So $c_n$ is $c'_n$ to make $x=1$, $c_n=A_n+B_n=1!+2!+\cdots+(n-1)!+n!$.

For $b_n$, you can do it similarly (although there is no closed form). You can see $b'_n$ as functions: $b'_n(x)=1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\cdots+\sqrt{n+x}}}$, so we have $b'_{n+1}=b_n'(\sqrt{n+1+x})$. However, there may be no yield...

Answer (score -2):

$c_n$ is th Hörner factorization of :
$$1! + 2! + 3! + \cdots + n!$$
In fact :

- $1! + 2! + 3! = 3! + 2! + 1! = 3 \times 2 \times 1 + 2 \times 1 + 1 = ((3 + 1) \times 2 + 1) \times 1 = c_3$.
- $\begin{array}[t]{lcl}
  1! + 2! + 3! + 4! & = & 4! + 3! + 2! + 1! \\[2mm]
  & = & 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 + 3 \times 2 \times 1 + 2 \times 1 + 1 \\[2mm]
  & = & (((4 + 1) \times 3 + 1) \times 2 + 1) \times 1 = c_4
  \end{array}$.
- $\begin{array}[t]{lcl}
  1! + 2! + \cdots + n! & = & n! + \cdots + 2! + 1! \\[2mm]
  & = & n \times (n - 1) \times \cdots \times 1 + \cdots + 2 \times 1 + 1 \\[2mm]
  & = & (\dots(((n + 1) \times (n - 1) + 1) \times \cdots + 1) 2 + 1) \times 1 = c_n
  \end{array}$.